# How do I read a video of raspberry pi being sent to notebook using opencv?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, opencv, raspberry-pi

I want to read http(streaming) sent via raspberry pie on opencv in notebook's anaconda virtual environment but I don't know how.
Pi is connected to the notebook's mobile hotspot and is streaming via MJPG Streamer.
I checked that it's streaming.
I asked ChatGpt and I used that code

```
import cv2

url = 'http://192.168.0.100:8080/?action=stream'
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(url)

while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if not ret:
        print('Failed to read frame from camera stream.')
        break
    
    cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I want to receive streaming through the camera of raspberry pi and use the tensorflow of the PC to recognize objects in real time on the PC

However, in the cv2.VideoCapture section, an error occurs that fails to read the path.

How do I enable opencv to read the path of the video

Comment: You didn't show how the Raspberry Pi is set up to stream, or its IP address, or how you checked it. Nor did you show the error message.